# zend 2 + Doctrine 2 returned checkbox values

Tags: forms, checkbox, doctrine, zend-framework2

I am using zend 2 and doctrine 2

I am not clear how to return and populate a database with returned values from a checkbox. The values should return multiple entries for the table.

I cannot find any documentation/articles on how to render or use a check box; so, I would really appreciate advice or sample code on this.

I have enclosed my class below. I believe that the problem is occurring in my entity class: i.e I am not properly using the getter/setter for an array collection, consequently I keep getting the error message, from my returned postform, that my returned values are empty.

Here is my code:

**My mysql table:**

```
CREATE TABLE workers_timetable(
id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
timesId MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
INDEX (id ,timesId ), 
INDEX times_id (timesId, id ) 

);
```

**My Class;**

```
<?php

namespace Workers\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\Factory as InputFactory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface; 

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;


/**
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="workers_timetable")
 * @property int $timesId
 */
class WorkersAvailabilityTimeTable {

   /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer");
     */
    protected $timesId;




    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->timesId = new ArrayCollection();
    }


   public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    } 



   public function addTimesId(Collection $timesId)
    {
        foreach ($timesId as $timesId) {
            $this->setTimesId($this);
            $this->timesId->add($timesId);
        }
    }

    public function setTimesId()
    {
        return $this->timesId;
    }


    public function removeTimesId(Collection $timesId)
    {
        foreach ($timesId as $timesId) {
            $this->setTimesId(null);
            $this->timesId->removeElement($timesId);
        }
    }

    public function getTimesId()
    {
        return $this->timesId;
    }


    //put your code here
}
```

**my fieldSet class**

```
<?php

namespace Workers\Form\Fieldset;

use Workers\Entity\WorkersAvailabilityTimeTable;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterProviderInterface;



class WorkersAvailabilityTimeTableFieldset extends Fieldset implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
   public function __construct(ObjectManager $objectManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('WorkerTimeTable');


        $this->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($objectManager, 'Workers\Entity\WorkersAvailabilityTimeTable'))
             ->setObject(new WorkersAvailabilityTimeTable());


        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'id',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Hidden',
        ));

         $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox',
            'name' => 'timesIds',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Please Select Your Availablity',
                'value_options' => array(

                    '1'  =>'mon',
                    '2' =>'tues'
   ),
            ),
            'attributes' => array(
                'value' => '1' //set checked to '1'
            )
        ));
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'd want to use `DoctrineModule\Form\Element\ObjectMultiCheckbox`. Refer to [the DoctrineModule\docs](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/form-element.md) for more Information.

Second of things would be you doing something wrong inside your Entity if I'm not completely dumb right now...

```
public function addTimesId(Collection $timesId)
{
    foreach ($timesId as $timesId) {
        $this->setTimesId($this);      // This should be $timesId->setWorker($this);
        $this->timesId->add($timesId);
    }
}
```

See more information about the later, again, at [the DoctrineModule\docs](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/master/docs/hydrator.md#example-3--onetomany-association)

Comment: how Sam. thank you for responding. i still cannnot seem to get it to work. i am still getting null values. when you mentioned that i should set my addTimesId() to $timesId->setworker($ythis); the set worker , should that be the name of the class.? i.e the name of the class is: WorkersAvailabilityTimeTableFieldset

Comment: please. does anyone have any working examples of how to use the checkbox. there are no tutorials or example of useing doctrine 2 and checkboxes; this makes it a nightmare for new users like myself to learn how to use zend/doctrine. i would really appriciate any help or advice

Comment: Use the ObjectMultiCheckbox and use it exactly as the ObjectSelect provided in the tutorial. The only difference is the ElementName, the rest works identical.